# consumo de web servicios con javacript y poder enviar datos a ese servicio?

Tags: javascript, servicio

la idea es que tengo un

```js
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "988d19f6-4555-484a-aeab-c8c27fe8ea87"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\n\t\"auth_key\": \"ffa07465e5af0a0f69d776e3a288dea1\",\n\t\"entity_number\": \"4006\",\n\t\"contact_identification\": \"123555555\",\n\t\"contact_name\": \"juan PEREZ\",\n\t\"contact_email\": \"juan@email.com\",\n\t\"contact_phone\": \"9999999\",\n\t\"contact_fax\": \"9999999\",\n\t\"contact_address\": \"CALLE 33# 23-43\",\n\t\"city_name\": \"Bogota\",\n\t\"contact_position_name\": \"DIRECTOR\",\n\t\"description\": \"CASO REGISTRADO POR EL USUARIO\"\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

pero no se puede con el html que tengo consumir este servicio

```html
 <div class="container" id="informacion">
    <form action="procesar.php" method="post" name="frm">
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">identificacion</label>
       <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="clave" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputAddress">cargo</label>
    <input name="cargo" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="cargo">
    </div>
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">identificacion</label>
       <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="idnt" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputAddress">cargo</label>
    <input name="cargo" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="cargo">
    </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <label for="inputAddress">Nombre</label>
             <input name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Nombre">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
    
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Telefono</label>
       <input name="tel" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Telefono">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputAddress">Fax</label>
    <input name="fax" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Fax">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Direccion</label>
    <input type="text" name="dir" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label  for="inputCity">Ciudad</label>
      <input name="ciudad" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
    <label  for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Descripción</label>
    <textarea name="desp" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <button type="button" id="btn btn-primary" >envio</button>
</form>
  
</div>
<div class="notificacion"></div>
    <footer>
        
    </footer>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#btn btn-primary').click(function(){
           $ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            type : "POST",  
            ContentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/",
            data : JSON.stringinfy({clave: $('auth_key').val() , cedula: $('entity_number').val() ,  idnt: $('contact_identification').val() , name: $('contact_name').val() , Email: $('contact_email').val() , Telefono: $('contact_phone').val() , fax: $('contact_fax').val() , dir: $('contact_address').val() , ciudad: $('city_name').val() ,cargo: $('contact_position_name').val() ,desp: $('"description').val() }),
            success : function(data){
              $('.notificacion').html("<p>" + data.d + "<p>" );
            },
            error: function() {
              alert (" error")
            }
           
         
           });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

no lo puedo consumir

Comment: Si no me equivoco tu primer error está en $('#btn btn-primary') ya que el id debe ser sin espacios, segundo no puedes agregar una clase en un id. En dado caso debería ir  <button type="button" id="idBoton" class="btn btn-primary" >envio</button>

Comment: si era un error , mio pero igual no funciona genera dos errores esta mal echo el post .. sigo en busqueda de poder hacerle un buen pos para agregar datos ,

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los errores que genera? ¿Cuál de los dos códigos Ajax estás usando?  ¿Cómo manejas la petición en el servidor?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            type : "POST",  
            ContentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/",
            data : JSON.stringify({clave: $('auth_key').val() , cedula: $('entity_number').val() ,  idnt: $('contact_identification').val() , name: $('contact_name').val() , Email: $('contact_email').val() , Telefono: $('contact_phone').val() , fax: $('contact_fax').val() , dir: $('contact_address').val() , ciudad: $('city_name').val() ,cargo: $('contact_position_name').val() ,desp: $('description').val() }),
            success : function(data){
              $('.notificacion').html("<p>" + data.d + "<p>" );
            },
            error: function() {
              alert (" error")
            }


           });
```